# How to use def-return or for-in statements on dataframes to avoid repetitions in code in python /pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, repeat

could someone please look at below code and advice what I have done wrong.

I have 2 panda dataframes - df and x1 
Both have the same columns and column names

I have to execute below set of codes for df.Date_Appointment, x1.Date_Appointment and similary for df.Date_Scheduled and x1.Date_Scheduled. As such created a list for columns and dataframes.

I am trying to write a single code but obviously I am doing something wrong. Please advice.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file1.csv)
x1 = pd.read_csv(file2.csv)
```

`# x1 is a dataframe created after filtering on one column.
    # df and x1 have same number of columns and column names
    # x1 is a subset of df` ``

```
dataframe = ['df','x1']
column = ['Date_Appointment', 'Date_Scheduled']

def df_det (dataframe.column):

    (for df_det in dataframe.column :

        d_da = df_det.describe()
        mean_da = df_det.value_counts().mean()
        median_da = df_det.value_counts().median()
        mode_da = df_det.value_counts().mode()

        print('Details of all  appointments', '\n', 

         d_da, '\n',
         'Mean = ', mean_da,'\n', 
         'Median = ', median_da,'\n',
         'Mode = ',mode_da,'\n'))
```

Please indicate the steps.
Thank  you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you function should have two arguments -- `dataframe` and `column` -- both of which are lists, so I made the names plural.

Then you need to loop over each argument. Note that you are also assigning a dataframe in the function the same name as your function, so I changed the name of the function.

```
dataframes = [dataframe1, dataframe2]
columns = ['Date_Appointment', 'Date_Scheduled']

def summary_stats(dataframes, columns):
    for df in dataframes:
        for col in cols:
            df_det = df.loc[:, col]
            # print summary stats about df_det
```

Comment: Thank you for responding in detail. The code is working now without errors but producing no output. The code gave me a lot of errors initially. I couldn't understand why. finally figured it out. It was incorrect indentation. I was not aware that each line should begin at exactly the same order and spacing that is in your code above. I am new to programming. Would help if you could please clarify as to why am I not getting an output onscreen despite the 'print' statement.

Comment: In addition to confirming why the print command did not result in an output, could you also provide the code for calling the program once again at a later stage in the project on another set of dataframes and variables. Thanks in advance